# Objdump: What does the comment mean?

Tags: assembly, objdump

I'm trying to write a small os kernel and got an General Protection Fault at runtime. By logging the `qemu` output, I figured out, that the following assembly is responsible:

`10592e:    48 c7 05 a7 5c 02 00    movq   $0x12b5a0,0x25ca7(%rip) # 12b5e0 <watch+0x40>`

Can someone tell me, what the `<watch+0x40>` stand for? I think `watch` means my `Watch` class, but what is the `+0x40`?

Comment: No, `watch` would refer to a global variable named `watch` or maybe a function with that name. The `watch+0x40` means that the instruction is storing the value at address of `watch` plus 64 (0x40). If `watch` is big enough then that location might be a part of it. Otherwise it's storing the value in some unnamed object that lies beyond `watch` in memory.

Comment: It is very likely storing it in a member variable of the `Watch` class. Hard to say for sure without seeing more code. Why didn't you post a [MCVE]?